# C# ASP.Net RadioButtonList within table: <td> border also creating border arount LIST ITEMS

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-table, border, radiobuttonlist

I have created a table with borders collapsed around the table and a small gray border on each `<td>`.  However the border is also surrounding each radio button items.  The border attribute on the radio button appears to affect another border.  How do I delete the border created on the `<td>` tag from the radio button list items?

```
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
                <asp:Label ID="lblJoint"  CssClass="boldIt" runat="server" Text="Is this for a joint account?" style="float: left; width: 200px;"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdlJoint" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="130px" style="float: left;" BorderStyle="None">
                    <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">No</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/forums/radiobuttonlist-css-item-no-borders/p/3326/31807.aspx

Comment: I've already set the Border-Width to 0; the border I'm getting on the RadioButtonList items is coming from the <td> tag.

Comment: Have you tryed `table border="0"` or `border-collapse` ?

Comment: I want borders for each cell (<td>) and I have set border-collapse on the table.  The problem is that the <td> border is also setting borders around the radio button items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Flow` RepeatLayout for RadioButtonList or create new css class for it : `table.noBorder td { border: none; }` and use this class for your radiobuttonlist

Answer (score 3):

Susan,
From what I can tell, when asp radiobuttonlist method is used, by default it creates a table with each radio button as a separate td. The newly created table inherits the css class of the next table up the heirarchy. If you use the 'RepeatLayout="Flow"' attribute, it will convert them to spans using the cssclass you define in the radiobuttonlist definition. Hope that helps.

Oops, just looked at the date. This is a little old, but maybe helpful.

Answer (score 0):

add `style="border: none;"` as attribute to the td-element

Comment: I require borders for the <td> elements, just not the radio button items.

Comment: sorry, my fault ;). What you could do is checking the generated html/css with Firebug (Firefox addon -> brilliant). It will show you wich css is used and where it is defined. Its at least a good start.

Answer (score 0):

When Asp.Net is interpreted as HTML, by default,  tags are placed around each radio button item.  If you have set a style on the  element in your table, it will also be inherited by the radio button elements.  To turn the border off on  styling off, use the following property on the radio button control:  RepeatLayout="Flow".

The border property on the radio button control is a separate border.