# How to remove border of the asp.net radio button

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a radio button like below, and i am unable to delete the border of  that radio button in IE. The same is working in Chrome.

```
<fieldset id="fsdeSign">
            <table width="98%">
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" colspan="2">
                        <div id="divName" runat="server" visible="false">
                            <span>
                                <label class="required" runat="server" id="Label1" style="width: 90px">
                                    <span id="NameSpan" runat="server">*</span>Name</label></span>                           
                            <asp:TextBox ID="textName" runat="server" MaxLength="20"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </td>

                    <td align="right">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblaccount" Style="display: none" runat="server" Width="155px"
                            Text="Would you like to use your account?"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblaccount" runat="server" Style="display: none;border-style:none;" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Yes" Text="Yes" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="No" Text="No" Selected="True" />
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    </td>                    
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
```

I have used the below cssclass="Sign" which is not reflecting.Do i need add any more tags?

```
fieldset#fseSign  input.Sign
{
    border-style:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  this  fieldset#fsdeSign input
{border-style: none;}

Comment: I tried this but other textbox : textName is loosing border

Comment: May be you can try border style for textName to solid

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `BorderStyle="None"` within `<asp: RadioButtonList>`. Your code should look like this:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblaccount" runat="server" Style="display: none" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" BorderStyle="None">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Yes" Text="Yes" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="No" Text="No" Selected="True" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

In any case, try to have a look at this similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384220/c-sharp-asp-net-radiobuttonlist-within-table-td-border-also-creating-border-a).
In case it does not work, it is also possible that you have to edit its `css` in the following way:

```
input[type="radio"] {
    border-style:none;
}
```

Comment: Its not working. I have tried all the options mentioned in that link.

Comment: I have tried that part already and it is working. But i am facing the issue in multiple page. So i cant add the below in every page. Is there a way for this??
<style type="text/css">
    input[type="radio"] { border-style:none; }
</style>

Comment: So in this way, you mean that for each page you are using a different css, right? What about importing a specific file.css for each page, and also a general one where then you can type my answer?